# Most appropriate roof rack style for carbon framed mountain bike?

Tags: carbon, transport-by-car

I have a CC Carbon Santa Cruz Hightower, which I would very much like to look after the frame. I have read in a couple of places that it can be dangerous/damaging to clamp onto carbon frames, so does this rule out the standard style of roof rack in which the wheels are held by small ratchet cinches and an arm clamps onto the downtube? Should i instead buy a different style of rack the clamps the front wheel or uses the thu axle?

Cheers.

Comment: Rest assured that your carbon frame is strong enough to handle the compression from a strap or whatever. If not, I believe SC does have a lifetime no questions asked warranty.